# How to prevent data loss when user session expired?

Tags: java, session, web-applications

I have a web app, which session expired in 30 minutes. At client side, when the user tries to interact with server and server detects user session is expired, the client will simply redirects to log in page.

The problem is, user may not know his session is expired, and keep working **on client side**(say, writing a note, or edit something), when he tries to send the changes to server, bad thing occurs, the browser redirects to log in page and user data is lost.

Any idea on how to prevent data loss when user session expired? Thanks.

Comment: You *should* save *data* into `database` or `file` system instead of `session`.

Comment: what is the action that will cause the user to stay idle for 30 mins?

Answer (score 0):

If the user is writing a note or editing anything on his session the session should not expire.

You can easily send a keep-alive message to the server for every 5th (or even more) character he presses keeping the session alive.

Comment: That's not totally true: user can be writing in a form without triggering any call to server. Even if you send a keep alive it may be true that user has written tons of data and left the form open for 30 minutes of inactivity and when he presses "POST" data is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered raising the session timeout? 30 minutes is pretty low. It might take some users longer than that to fill in one Web form, even if they are working continuously. My session timeouts are 8-10 hours. The only reason to make them shorter is to save space at the server. Is that a problem that you really have?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to provide some sort of support in the server. A good implementation would be a servlet called every 31 minutes of user "iddleness" (to avoid revalidating session which would cause it to never expire) from the client via an AJAX call.

If the session id changes in the server it would reply so and the client could show some sort of message.

An easier implementation would be firing some kind of reload every 31 minutes of inactivity, so that the user is redirected to the login page. That wouldn't need any extra support in the server, but would be less user-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

There are reasons to have short session time out.

1. Security
2. Data Theft

If you don't need those, just extend the session time out.
    OR,
Insert `AJAX calls` every where to renew the session.

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML you can have an alert after 29 minutes (JS setTimeout), and after 30min - 10s (meta refresh) do a jump to a "session expired" page.

Answer (score -1):

Session only expire if user will not done any action till 30 minutes.
If user did not do anything till 30 mins, then there should not be any data lost by idel session expired coz there is nothing to retain.

Comment: That's not totally true: user can be writing in a form without triggering any call to server.

Answer (score -1):

Please don't forget to add `{{ csrf_field() }}` in your form.

I had the same problem. Then, I put crsf token here! And, it works fine now. Here is my code:

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('customer.store')}}" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="row"> 
            //Your code here
        </div>
</form
```